# Laravel responsibility in the classes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a project on Laravel and need to do refactoring. I've read about Service provider and Dependency injection and have some questions.
This is a short structure: `user` model, `event` model, `favorite user` model and etc. Also, there are controllers for all models. Every `event` has a `creator` and `client` (`user` relationship). In every class, I am injecting appropriate service: `User` Service, `Event` service, `Favorite user` service and etc.
Let's consider the example - I want to `delete` the `user`:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var UserService $userService
     */
    protected $userService;

    /**
     * UserController constructor.
     * @param UserService $userService
     */
    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }
    protected function delete(int $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        if ($user) {
            $this->userService->setUser($user);
            $this->userService->delete();
        }
    }
```

Inside User service, I am processing user deleting - update the appropriate field. Also, I need to cancel all user events and delete favorite users.
My question is where should I do it? Should I inject `event` and `favorite user` service in `UserController` or in `UserService`? Or maybe there is a better way to do this action. Thx in advance

Comment: There is no 'best' way to do this, imo. Make sure that you are not breaking any OOP principles. And it seems to me that you are not. I would inject any additional services inside the user service class, but would do the resolving using an interface instead of a concrete class. (program to interface, not implementation)

Using events may seem like a good idea to load some burden off of the service class. But, if this is all the complexity to it, it seems like an overkill to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have many actions depending on deleting user, so I would consider using Events and inside each listener handle the specifics of it.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var UserService $userService
     */
    protected $userService;

    /**
     * UserController constructor.

     * @param UserService $userService
     */
    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    protected function delete(int $id)
    {
        if(!$this->userService->delete($id)) {
          // return some error;
        }

        event(new UserWasRemoved($id));
        // return success response
    }
```

```
class DeleteUserService {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function delete($id){
       return $this->user->delete($id);
    }
}
```

```
// app/Providers/EventServiceProvider

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        UserWasRemoved::class => [
            CancelUserEvents::class,
            RemoveUserFavorites::class,
            // etc...
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if deleting a user is much code,  I will create `DeleteUserService` class which will contain all the code needed to delete a user and the effects of the delete.

```
class DeleteUserService {

    public function __construct(int $userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    public function delete(){
         $this->deleteUser();
         $this->updateAppropriateFields();  // of course the name should be clearer
         $this->deleteEvents();
         $this->deleteFavoriteUser();
         ...
    }

    private function deleteUser(){...}
    private function updateAppropriateFields(){...}
    private function deleteEvents(){...}
    private function deleteFavoriteUser(){...}
    ...

}
```

and in your controller either you inject the service or instantiate a new instance  in the controller method

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function delete(int $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $deleteService = new DeleteUserService($user->id);
        $deleteService->delete();
    }
}
```

it's always a good idea to break your large function into one or more classes.

Comment: It means I have to create service for every "big" action. But what about reusing existing code? I should do some same actions during different actions. As an example, I need to delete favorite users during user deleting, event deleting and in several other places.  What should I do with it? Create the same function in every service, or put it in a different one? The main problem is there are a lot of relations between models, and I don't know how to use many services to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you abandon your approach to using services like this. Everything that you implement with services has already been implemented in Laravel, only even easier. You are now implementing more cumbersome logic on top of a simple, ready-made one.

1. For each object of your subject area (user, event, favorite user) add model class. Add in them the information of tables, the data from which belong to them - unless of course you use relational storage [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions). Here I have a question for you - does the favorite user entity need a separate class? If the User and the FavoriteUser have the same characteristics (that is, class members in the implementation), then there is no need to distribute them into different classes, and it is enough to add an additional isFavourite() (bool) attribute - in the class and in the table.
2. Implement the necessary methods in the controllers for each of your model classes as described in the documentation [Defining Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#defining-controllers). Depending on the type of the client part, the return of the response can be either JSON for the RESTful API, or a blade template with the transmitted data [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views). Here, in the controller, you should implement a method to delete the model.

If you do not want the logic to be similar, that is, get rid of the similar methods all(), get(), post(), put(), delete() and others for UserController, for EventController, ... (with the exception of model classes - which will be different), then I advise you use the following architectural trick (this is optional, of course). Develop a universal layer - a class of a universal model, a class of a universal controller, a class of a universal model repository (if you use it in development). And in the controller, describe the common logic for all model classes, all(), get(), post(), put(), delete(). And then inherit each concrete class of the model from the universal, each concrete class of the controller from the universal - and so on. But!
In a concrete class of the model, it is necessary, for example, in an array, to list the attributes of the relational storage table, where you get the data from; it is also necessary to specify the name of the class in the variable - so that the controller can understand which class it should work with.
And in the controller in any way pass data about the model class - for example, using DependencyInjection [Dependency Injection & Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers).
With this approach, the classes of concrete controllers become thin, and the increase in code in them occurs only due to the redefinition of universal methods or the implementation of custom ones.
The advantage of this approach is also that there is no need to add routes of a similar structure. For example, a universal route will suffice for you

```
Route::get('{entity}/{id}', function ($entity, $id) {
    $module = ucfirst($entity);
    Route::get("{$entity}/{$id}", "{$module}Controller@get");
});
```

instead of many of the same type

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@get');

Route::get('event/{id}', 'EventController@get');
```

and the like.

Comment: There is an existing project with standard Laravel structure with models, controllers and etc. I have to refactor it. As I said there are a lot of relations. You said to not use services, but I do not understand how to implement all needed to me actions from your answer.